# Mathematica only graphs the upper part of my cylinder

Tags: graphics, graphics3d, code-review

I have this code which first is supposed to make random points, draw lines through the points and then make these lines radical axes of cylinders. I have two problems with my code. First, it only draws the upper half of cylinders.  Second, the perspectives are really messed up, somehow twisted and uneven. For example, `Show[a, ViewPoint -> Front, ImageSize -> Large, Boxed -> False]` should be looking from a perspective where xy-plane is completely straight (perpendicular to z axis) but thats not what is happening. Here is my code:

```
plane = InfinitePlane[{{0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}}];
     pts = RandomPoint[plane, 20, {{-10, 10}, {-10, 10}, {0, 0}}];
     a = Graphics3D[{plane, 
        Cylinder[{#, # + {#[[2]], -#[[1]], 
              4 Sqrt[3] Sqrt[#[[1]]^2 + #[[2]]^2] + 7}}, 1/2] & /@ pts, 
        Red, InfiniteLine[#, {#[[2]], -#[[1]], 
            4 Sqrt[3] Sqrt[#[[1]]^2 + #[[2]]^2] + 7}] & /@ pts, Black, 
        Sphere[{0, 0, 0}, 0.3], Blue, Sphere[pts, .1]}, 
        PlotRange -> {{-10, 10}, {-10, 10}, {-10, 10}}]
     Show[a, ImageSize -> Large, Boxed -> False]
     Show[a, ViewPoint -> Above, ImageSize -> Large, Boxed -> False]
     Show[a, ViewPoint -> Front, ImageSize -> Large, Boxed -> False]
     Show[a, ViewPoint -> {0, 0, \[Infinity]}, ImageSize -> Large, 
      Boxed -> False]
     Show[a, ViewPoint -> {0, -\[Infinity], 0}, ImageSize -> Large, 
      Boxed -> False]
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: use `Cylinder[{# - {#[[2]], -#[[1]], 
      4 Sqrt[3] Sqrt[#[[1]]^2 + #[[2]]^2] + 7}, # + {#[[2]], -#[[1]], 
      4 Sqrt[3] Sqrt[#[[1]]^2 + #[[2]]^2] + 7}}, 1/2] & /@ pts` to have the cylinders extend below `plane`.

Comment: @kglr that worked! What is the meaning behind $#-$ and $#+$ I did this by imitating someone else's code. Could you point me to a reference? That does not fix the perspective problem though, any ideas?

Comment: Sorfosh, look up `Function` and `Slot` in the docs.

Comment: Solved! I just had to reset Mathematica and kglr helped with the main issue. This can be closed or @kglr add your comment as a response

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
Cylinder[{# - {#[[2]], -#[[1]], 4 Sqrt[3] Sqrt[#[[1]]^2 + #[[2]]^2] + 7},
  # + {#[[2]], -#[[1]], 4 Sqrt[3] Sqrt[#[[1]]^2 + #[[2]]^2] + 7}}, 1/2] & /@ pts
```

in `Graphics3D` that poduces `a` to have the cylinders extend below `plane`.

```
Show[a, ViewPoint -> Front, ImageSize -> Large, Boxed -> False]
```

[image]